# Add URL parameter on loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where there is a form which is used to **Add / Edit Addresses**.

In the right section of the page, there is a saved address Which has `Edit` link and it gives call to the same page URL with adding a new parameter say **"billingID.XXXXX"**.

After clicking on this link, page is re loaded with the default address data auto filled.

I need this to happen on the first time load. I tried triggering `click` event on this Edit link on load, but I suppose it is not allowed by **jQuery**.

What are the other options I have with **jQuery** / **javascript** to add this URL parameter on load of page.?

Comment: try `$( "#edit" ).trigger( "click" );`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Javascript History API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, I didn't understand you quite clear.

If you need the page to be reloaded and show the page by url, you can get 'href' value by jquery and then call `window.location = $('.mylink').attr('href') + '?billingID.XXXXX';`.

If you just want to replace url in browser panel, you can use History API as Kahuna suggested. E.g. you can call

```
window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, window.location.path + '?helloworld=1');
```

but then you have to update the page contents by yourself, using JS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
if(window.location.href == 'requestd page href'){//http://localhost/test/test.php
 window.location.href += "?billingID.XXXXX";
}
```